# Change schema of dataframe to other schema

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I hava dataframe that looks like this

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- foo01 string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar01 string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- foo02 string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar02 string (nullable = true)
```

and I want to transform it to

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- foo01 string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- foo02 string (nullable = true)
 |-- bar: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar01 string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar02 string (nullable = true)
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [struct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) Pyspark function.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct

new_df = df.select(
  'id',
  struct('data.foo01', 'data.foo02').alias('foo'),
  struct('data.bar01', 'data.bar02').alias('bar'),
)
```

Additional note related to the struct Pyspark function: It can either take a list of string column names to only move columns into the struct or if you need a list of expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this answer. Just one additional question, that I didn't specify in my original question: What would I do if I would want to rename `foo01` into `foo99`?

Comment: The you can use `struct(F.col('data.foo01').alias('new_name'), F.col('data.foo02').alias('other_new_name'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use struct function with select as below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

finalDF = df.select( "id",
                     F.struct("data.foo01", "data.foo02").alias("foo"),
                     F.struct("data.bar01", "data.bar02").alias("bar")
                     )


finalDF.printSchema
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- foo01: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- foo02: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bar: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- bar01: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bar02: string (nullable = true)
```